# VNSTAT only giving stats for the month of June

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-monitoring

I MUST be overlooking something here.  The date and time are set correctly on my machine, but VNSTAT only shows stats for the month of June (vnstat -m).

Everything is updated and appears to be running fine.  I feel like this is something simple that I am overlooking.

EDIT  vnstat -d shows traffic for the month of June also

EDIT  simply running vnstat, without any arguments, outputs the following (screenshot)

[image: vnstat]

Comment: What is the output of vnstat without arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ran vnstat with some different switches and noticed that eth0 was disabled sometimes.  So I enabled it as SU and now it appears to be working fine.

I did this about a week ago and today the output looks as expected.

Thanks for all the help in the past ServerFault community!